# Expected method to read array element not found of object type 'NSString *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)convert_button:(id)sender {
NSString * binary_input = _binary_field.text;
if(binary_input!=NULL)
{
    int count, total, i, j, tmp;
    total = 0;
    count = binary_input.length;

    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        if (binary_input[count-i] == '1') {//error here saying Expected method to read array element not found of object type 'NSString *'
            tmp = 1;
            for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
                tmp *= 2;
            total += tmp;
        }
    }
    long decimal_value = strtol([binary_input UTF8String], NULL, 2);
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithFormat: @"%li", decimal_value];
    _decimal_output.text = resultString;
}
```

}

I am getting an error as commented in the code at my if statement that error says Expected method to read array element not found of object type 'NSString *'

I am new to objective-c and have mainly have done c++, any help is appreciated in how to fix the error, the logic makes sense to me.

Comment: You can't index an NSString.  Consult the documentation to find out how to access individual characters.

Comment: Use `[binary_input characterAtIndex:index]` instead.

Comment: that solved the problem KudoCC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    if (binary_input[count-i] == '1')
```

In your first iteration through the loop, you'll be looking for the element in spot -1, which is outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: you'll also get a crash at the last element in the array. You'll want to go until `i < count`

Comment: how is that? i starts at 0 and my count starts at how long my string is.

Comment: arrays are indexed 0-based. The way you have it, if you have 1 item in your array, then your loop with go from 0 up to (and INCLUDING) 1. The last item in an array will be 1-less than it's count.